How to apply Bootstrap Table
I am working on fetching data from an API into table format using JavaScript. I received the data perfectly but cannot apply Bootstrap onto the table header part.


async function Sports() {
  let Api = "https://inshortsapi.vercel.app/news?category=sports";
  let result = await (await fetch(Api)).json();

  document.write(`   <table class='table'>
                                <thead class='thead-dark'>
                                 <tr><th>SR NO</th>
                                     <th> AUTHOR NAME</th>
                                     <th>CONTENT</th>
                                     <th>DATE </th>
                                 </tr></thead>`);

  for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {

    document.write(`<tbody><tr>
                                        <td>${i+1}</td>
                                        <td>${result.data[i]["author"]}</td>
                                        <td>${result.data[i]["content"]}</td>
                                        <td>${result.data[i]["date"]}</td>
                                    </tr></tbody>`)
  }
  document.write("</table>")
}
Sports();
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



I want to Table like this []
I didn't get the result I wanted and got this type of table.


Have you inspected your rendered html to determine if the CSS is being applied?

Don't use document.write. It'll overwrite the page and remove your link to Bootstrap. Use innerHTML instead

I would also note that you're using bootstrap 5.3.3 for your CSS, but bootstrap 4.1.3 for your javascript. I would decide on one version to avoid running into unexpected behaviour in the future.

When you use document.write, you override all the HTML you have, so it deletes your import of Bootstrap.
You can use document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', "<table>...</table>") to append your element to what you already have.


async function Sports() {
  let Api = "https://inshortsapi.vercel.app/news?category=sports";
  let result = await (await fetch(Api)).json();

  let html = `   <table class='table'>
                                <thead class='table-dark'>
                                 <tr><th>SR NO</th>
                                     <th> AUTHOR NAME</th>
                                     <th>CONTENT</th>
                                     <th>DATE </th>
                                 </tr></thead>`

  for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {

    html += `<tbody><tr>
                                        <td>${i+1}</td>
                                        <td>${result.data[i]["author"]}</td>
                                        <td>${result.data[i]["content"]}</td>
                                        <td>${result.data[i]["date"]}</td>
                                    </tr></tbody>`
  }
  html += ("</table>")
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html)
}
Sports();
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



